# using canvas to draw rectangle within rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have to use canvas and output rectangles within rectangles (number of rectangles depends on how many I have put in the code) and the rectangles should fit nicely inside the previous one.  I'm really lost as to how to center the rectangles and have them fit inside the previous rectangle.  I know why my output is the way it is, but I'm not sure where to go from here.  This is what I have, any help will be greatly appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
             var c = canvas.getContext("2d");  //create HTML5 context object to enable draw methods
    drawNestedRectangles(c, 200, 100, 6, 500, 400, "red");
   
            };  
   
    

    
function drawNestedRectangles(context, whereX, whereY, howMany, width, height, color){ 
   
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(whereX, whereY, width, height);
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fill();
  
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  context.strokeStyle = color; 
  context.stroke();
  for(var i=0; i<howMany - 1; i++) {
   whereX = whereX - 5;
   whereY = whereY - 5;
   width = width - 5;
   height = height - 5;
   context.beginPath();
   context.rect(whereX, whereY, width, height);
   context.fill();
   context.lineWidth = 4;
   context.strokeStyle = color;
   context.stroke();
  }
        
   
   
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600">
        Your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas tag 
         
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply move the rectangle's in (add x and y values) and change the width and height accordingly like so (basically subtract it by 5 more to fit it inside the last one):

```
whereX = whereX + 5; 
whereY = whereY + 5;
width = width - 10; 
height = height - 10;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
             var c = canvas.getContext("2d");  //create HTML5 context object to enable draw methods
    drawNestedRectangles(c, 200, 100, 6, 500, 400, "red");
   
            };  
   
    

    
function drawNestedRectangles(context, whereX, whereY, howMany, width, height, color){ 
   

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(whereX, whereY, width, height);
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fill();
  
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  context.strokeStyle = color; 
  context.stroke();
  for(var i=0; i<howMany - 1; i++) {
   whereX = whereX + 5;
   whereY = whereY + 5;
   width = width - 10;
   height = height - 10;
   context.beginPath();
   context.rect(whereX, whereY, width, height);
   context.fill();
   context.lineWidth = 4;
   context.strokeStyle = color;
   context.stroke();
  }
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fillText("Hello", whereX + (width/2) , 
whereY + (height/2));
        
   
   
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600">
        Your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas tag 
         
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JamesC. Yes we just need to do: `context.fillText("Hello", whereX + (width/2) , whereY + (height/2))`. Basically placing the text in the center of out main triangle is the same as placing it in the last one. I've updated my question to add text in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace this part of the code

```
for(var i=0; i<howMany - 1; i++) {
    whereX = whereX - 5;
    whereY = whereY - 5;
    width = width - 5;
    height = height - 5;
```

With:

```
for (var i = 0; i < howMany - 1; i++) {
    whereX = whereX + context.lineWidth*2;
    whereY = whereY + context.lineWidth*2;
    width = width - context.lineWidth*4;
    height = height - context.lineWidth*4;
```

Now each square start 2 border widths after the previous one and ends 2 border widths before; both verticaly and horizontaly.